# Map reduce to delete duplicates (mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, pymongo

I have created map reduce function to get all documents along with their count.
I need to remove all the duplicates now. How should I do it?

```
 res = col.map_reduce(map,reduce,"my_results");
```

Gives output like:

```
{u'_id': u'http://www.hardassetsinvestor.com/features/5485-soft-commodity-q4-report-low-inventories-buoy-cocoa-growing-stocks-weigh-on-coffee-cotton-a-sugar.html', u'value': 2.0}
{u'_id': u'http://www.hardassetsinvestor.com/market-monitor-archive/5490-week-in-review-gold-a-silver-kick-off-2014-strongly-oil-a-natgas-stall.html', u'value': 2.0}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't care which duplicate gets removed, an easy approach is to ensure a unique index with [`dropDups:true`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/#drop-duplicates).

For example, assuming a field name of `url`:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { url: 1 }, { unique: true, dropDups: true } )
```

Important note from the [`dropDups` documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/#drop-duplicates):

> As in all unique indexes, if a document does not have the indexed field, MongoDB will include it in the index with a “null” value.
>   If subsequent fields do not have the indexed field, and you have set `{dropDups: true}`, MongoDB will remove these documents from the collection when creating the index. If you combine `dropDups` with the `sparse` option, this index will only include documents in the index that have the value, and the documents without the field will remain in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You would write a small application to do this, i.e. in the shell:

```
db.my_results.find().forEach(function(doc){
    if(doc.value > 1)
        db.realCollection.remove({_id: doc._id}, true);
});
```

The end `true` makes remove only remove once

#### Edit

Adding Python since the above code is hard to translate:

```
for doc in db.my_results.find():
    if doc.value > 1:
        for i in range(0, doc.value):
            db.realCollection.remove({'_id': doc._id}, true);
```

Comment: Can't I write this in python script(pymongo)?

Comment: @wannaC Sure I just don't know python terribly well currently

Comment: what is mrcollection here?

Comment: @wannaC it is actually my_results

Comment: @wannaC-edit the question to include your python code that doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you. But what if there are 4 duplicates, then remove will delete only one document, I will still have 3 more duplicates to delete.